# ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) argument --set-env-vars: Bad syntax for dict arg

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-code

I'm using **Cloud Code** (extension for Visual Studio Code) and during the **deploy**, via UI, I'm trying to set the **Environment Variables** field like this:

```
KEY1:value1
KEY2:value2,value3
```

But I'm having this error:

> Failed to deploy the app. Error: ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) argument --set-env-vars: Bad syntax for dict arg: [value3]. Please see `gcloud topic flags-file` or `gcloud topic escaping` for information on providing list or dictionary flag values with special characters. ,Usage: gcloud run deploy [[SERVICE] --namespace=NAMESPACE] [optional flags] optional flags may be --add-cloudsql-instances | --allow-unauthenticated | --args | --async | --binary-authorization | --breakglass | --clear-binary-authorization | --clear-cloudsql-instances | --clear-config-maps | --clear-env-vars | --clear-key | --clear-labels | --clear-post-key-revocation-action-type | --clear-secrets | --clear-vpc-connector | --cluster | --cluster-location | --command | --concurrency | --connectivity | --context | --cpu | --cpu-throttling | --env-vars-file | --help | --image | --ingress | --key | --kubeconfig | --labels | --max-instances | --memory | --min-instances | --namespace | --platform | --port | --post-key-revocation-action-type | --region | --remove-cloudsql-instances | --remove-config-maps | --remove-env-vars | --remove-labels | --remove-secrets | --revision-suffix | --service-account | --set-cloudsql-instances | --set-config-maps | --set-env-vars | --set-secrets | --source | --tag | --timeout | --no-traffic | --update-config-maps | --update-env-vars | --update-labels | --update-secrets | --use-http2 | --vpc-connector | --vpc-egress For detailed information on this command and its flags, run: gcloud run deploy --help

So it seems the **comma** needs to be escaped. How to do that via Cloud Code **UI**, please?

Comment: I gave up, and used dash `-` as delimiter and handled it in my code accordingly

Answer (score 4):

If you set the env-var like this: `--set-env-var "A=B,C,D"` to gcloud, it will treat the comma (,) character as another environment variable declaration and will try to split the value into multiple environment variables. This is explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/escaping) in detail.

However, to prevent splitting with commas, you need to specify a different custom delimiter that you’re sure won’t occur in your value string, such as ##:

```
--set-env-vars "^##^A=B,C,D"
```

You may also  use a format like this as mentioned in the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables#command-line):

```
--set-env-vars "^@^KEY1=value1,value2,value3@KEY2=..."
```

Comment: Of course, Mousumi, but as I said, I'm using Cloud Code extension. There is no command line, just an "Environment Variables" field, where I should provide key:value, one pair for each line. How to escape that?

Comment: Thanks!
This is especially useful if you want to pass some random string as an ENV (e.g: service account key)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a work around here.
We are working to fix this through https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-vscode/issues/560.

Answer (score 0):

For now I could solve that by making "Environment Variables" UI field `empty` and using a `Dockerfile` to set the variables, where this syntax works:

```
ENV KEY1='value1'
ENV KEY2='value2,value3'
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, putting a comma in between values in an env var when using the --set-env-vars or --update-env-vars commands will get interpreted as declaring a new env var (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/escaping).

A workaround I found was to swap out the comma for another punctuation mark/separator, e.g a semi-colon and then adapt my code to this new separator:

```
--set-env-vars KEY="val1;val2;val3"
```

I then just updated my Python code to something like below:

```
env_var = os.environ.get('KEY')
env_var_values = env_var.split(';') #instead of env_var.split(',')
```